# Backbone pass object with event

Tags: events, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

Reading up on tutorials of Backbone, it seems that when the `add` event is fired from a `collection`, the item added is sent along with the event (same goes for `remove`).  I can't find any documentation on this feature on the [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org/) site and was curious if there was a way I could send an object along with my custom `events`.  Secondly, is something like this possible in Marionette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each object defined by Backbone mixes in [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) which means you can trigger events with [`object.trigger`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger). It is defined as

> **trigger** object.trigger(event, [*args])
>   Trigger callbacks for the given event, or space-delimited list of events. Subsequent arguments
>   to trigger will be passed along to the event callbacks.

You just have to pass additional arguments to get them in your callbacks.

For example,

```
var m = new Backbone.Model();
m.on('custom', function(more) {
     console.log(more);
});
m.trigger('custom', 'more info');
```

will log `more info`

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/HpwXe/ for a demo

You would trigger an event with a reference to the object to emulate the behavior of backbone :

```
var m = new Backbone.Model();
m.on('custom', function(model, more) {
     console.log(arguments);
});
m.trigger('custom', m, 'more info');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/HpwXe/1/

And in a derived model:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    custom: function() {
        this.trigger('custom', this);
    }
});

var m = new M();
m.on('custom', function(model, more) {
     console.log(model);
});
m.custom();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/HpwXe/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can use  Backbone.Event

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend();
collection = new collection();
collection.on("message", function(message){
  console.log(message);
});

var model = new Backbone.Model();
collection.add(model);
model.trigger("message", "This is message");
```

About what types of events you can see to backbone [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events).

This is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/HpwXe/)

Also you can use [Event Aggregato](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr)r from Marionette.js

An event aggregator implementation. It extends from Backbone.Events to provide the core event handling code in an object that can itself be extended and instantiated as needed.

```
var vent = new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();

vent.on("foo", function(){
  console.log("foo event");
});

vent.trigger("foo");
```